# I want to extract seller ID and merchant ID from the string

Tags: sql

[Merchant ID and Seller ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWd93.png),

The values of seller and merchant ID may differ from case to case.
I used the bellow code but its not fetching the data correctly. CAN ANYONE HELP.

```sql
    SELECT
        details,
        CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', a.em) <> 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING(a.em, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', a.em) -1)
            ELSE SUBSTRING(a.am, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', a.am) -1)             
        END seller_id
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                details,
                SUBSTRING(
                    details,
                    CHARINDEX('Seller ID:', details) + 11,
                    LEN(details)
                ) em,
                SUBSTRING(
                    details,
                    CHARINDEX('Merchant ID: ',details) +11,
                    LEN(details)
                    ) am
           FROM MY_TABLE
```

Comment: provide sample data and your expected ouput in table format

Comment: @Fahmi,

ID
1639497081,
2083473471 

Sample attached in the hyper Link "Merchant ID and Seller ID",

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and string functions are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) not as (hardly readable) screen shots. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.